# SKSpriteNode stretching when manually animating textures

Tags: ios, animation, sprite-kit, stretch

I have a fairly simple animation with 8 identically sized images. I'm not using the built in animation methods as I want to manually control the speed of the animation on the fly. I'm using preloaded SKTexture's and doing [object setTexture:texture]; inside of the update:currentTime method.

The problem is that sometimes the texture gets really distorted/stretched. After a lot of debugging, I have narrowed it down to only happening when the node is stationary. In fact, if I move the node a pixel and move it back like this, the problem never occurs:

```
[self setTexture:texture];
CGPoint currentPosition = self.position;
self.position = CGPointMake(currentPosition.x + 1, currentPosition.y + 1);
self.position = currentPosition;
```

This feels *extremely* hacky to me. I think under the hood, it's triggering a redraw on the parent node. Has anyone else experienced this? I have two major questions. 1) What is the cause? and 2) How can I resolve this without resorting to a hack?

Here is a normal frame and a stretched version (I apologize for the quality, placeholder art...)

[image: not-stretched]
[image: streched]

**Edit: After a few comments, I realized that I forgot to mention that I scaled the size of the node smaller than the size of the texture. Even though the textures are the same size, applying a new texture to a node with a smaller size causes the bug.**

Comment: others have had the same problem - it may be a bug in SK. Perhaps this is fixed in ios 7.1 beta.

Comment: Try adding [self setSize:texture.size];

Comment: @DobroćudniTapir that worked for me. I prefer that. I had been scaling the sprite down, so now I just rescale it every time I apply the texture. Do you want to add that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that upon setting the texture using [setTexture:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKSpriteNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKSpriteNode/texture) sprite node doesn't change it size, until being moved, resized, etc...

You can resolve this by manually setting the [size](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKSpriteNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKSpriteNode/size) after setting the texture.

```
[spriteNode setTexture:texture];
[spriteNode setSize:texture.size];
```